# ObjectListView faded away

Tags: objectlistview

can someone tell me why my ObjectListView fade after I installed Visual Studio 2008 sp1 and dot.net framework 3.5 sp 1.
What's wrong, some switch or what ...? (opaque?!)

Answer (score 0):

Does the control look washed out? There was a bug that shows up on 16-bit displays on the v2.3 release.

If you get the latest version of [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) from the SVN ([instructions here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/download.html#bleeding-edge-source)), this has been fixed.